# How can I can loop out html code in wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress

I have over 100 items in a list each manually coded into a Wordpress file. The problem is that its not DRY and the guy who wrote the code no longer works here. I've been asked to make some changes but to do so, I'd have to manually go through each section/item and make the changes myself. Ideally, I'd like to somehow output these sections in a loop.

I don't really know where to start for something like this. I was wondering if someone might be able to point me in the right direction. Do I need to use JS in script tags and output the HTML there?

here is an example of the sections

```
            <hr class='uk-grid-divider'>
            <div class='uk-grid'>
                <div class="uk-width-1-3"><p>2.60mm / .102″</p></div>
                <div class='uk-width-1-3'><p>300mm / 12"</p></div>
                <div class='uk-width-1-3'><p>10 Pieces</p></div>
            </div>
            <hr class='uk-grid-divider'>
            <div class='uk-grid'>
                <div class="uk-width-1-3"><p>2.61mm / .103″</p></div>
                <div class='uk-width-1-3'><p>300mm / 12"</p></div>
                <div class='uk-width-1-3'><p>10 Pieces</p></div>
            </div>
            <hr class='uk-grid-divider'>
            <div class='uk-grid'>
                <div class="uk-width-1-3"><p>2.62mm / .103″</p></div>
                <div class='uk-width-1-3'><p>300mm / 12"</p></div>
                <div class='uk-width-1-3'><p>10 Pieces</p></div>
            </div>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is really incomplete. We have no idea where to even start to help you. Where is this data stored? Is it the database? If all of that information is hardcoded into a file, I would highly recommend looking into Advanced Custom Fields, specifically a repeater type field.

Comment: @disinfor All of the information is hardcoded into a single WordPress file. My plan of action as of this moment is to do the changes manually, then to find a way to make it more maintainable. I'll be sure to check out Advanced Custom Fields, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: As a side note, you may want to convert each `uk-grid` into a row in a csv file and import that data into ACF fields if that's the route you go.

Comment: When the know how is missing it is sometimes easier to do things by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PHP code in your template or page because it's wordpress language.

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) : 
    $varFirst = 2.60 + 0.01 * $i; 
    $varSecond = 102 + $i;
?>

<hr class='uk-grid-divider'>
<div class='uk-grid'>
    <div class="uk-width-1-3"><p><?=$varFirst;?>mm / .<?=$varSecond;?>″</p></div>
    <div class='uk-width-1-3'><p>300mm / 12"</p></div>
    <div class='uk-width-1-3'><p>10 Pieces</p></div>
</div>

<?php endfor;?>
```

There are variables `$varFirst` and `$varSecond`. I adapted them for your dynamic values in the example.

*You can use it only in .php files*

Comment: We don't know if this will work. What if the data doesn't increase by `1`? We only have a very small sampling of more than 100 records.

Comment: May be you're right, bro. I put the solution for these specific initial conditions and for this task - it's a decision. If there are more than 100 record - we can increase iterations - it's easy. If variables begin from other number than 2.60, we can start from another number and edit the code. But it's a basis to get solution of this task.

Comment: @krolovolk I appreciate your help! I tried to use both a plugin and your solution, however I was unable to get either to work. As such I did it manually. I was not able to figure out why your solution would not work, as far as I could tell it wasn't looping. Wordpress does use php, however maybe the file for the page I'm editing does not run php?

Comment: @WebsiteDesigner may be it'll be easier to use text editor like [SublimeText](https://www.sublimetext.com/3) with special plugins like [Emmet](https://emmet.io/) to create and edit arrays of data with html syntax manual